# How to say "consecutive", but not necessarily one immediately after the other?

Tags: time

I have some event that happens e.g., every year.

I see that there is some strong correlation between the properties of events that occurred in the past, and those that occur in the future. I want to say this shortly, like: "there is strong correlation between different events that occur in consecutive years".
But this implies that the correlation is between this year's event and the next (right??), not the one which will occur five years from now.

So what should I replace the word "consecutive" with, in order to maintain the reference to the temporal ordering, but not limit it to years which come immediately one after the other?

Thanks!

Comment: You are correct ibn saying that _consecutive_ has the specific meaning 'following immediately one after another'. You could use _subsequent_ for non-consecutive years.

Comment: It sounds like you must simply state the distinction between the "subsequent" and any "previous/prior" events which correlate. Is that not a "brief" enough description? - e.g. the correlations between "past and future" (previous vs. subsequent) events.

Comment: @Kate & user22542, thanks! I admit "subsequent" simply does the job. I completely forgot about this option, quite embarrassing actually.. :). Should I now delete the question, as it's too trivial?